# How to format csv file properly?

Tags: c++

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream myfile;

    const int numberOfInputs = 9;
    std::string nameArray[numberOfInputs] = {""};
    int ageArray[numberOfInputs] = {0};

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfInputs; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a name: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, nameArray[i]);
        std::cout << "Enter an age: ";
        std::cin >> ageArray[i];

        std::cin.get();
        myfile << nameArray[i], ageArray[i], " \n";
    }

    myfile.open("People.csv");
    myfile << "Name, Age, \n";
    myfile << nameArray[1], ageArray[1], " \n";
    myfile << nameArray[2], ageArray[2], " \n";
    myfile << nameArray[3], ageArray[3], " \n";
    myfile << nameArray[4], ageArray[4], " \n";
    myfile << nameArray[5], ageArray[5], " \n";
    myfile << nameArray[6], ageArray[6], " \n";
    myfile << nameArray[7], ageArray[7], " \n";
    myfile << nameArray[8], ageArray[8], " \n";
    myfile << nameArray[9], ageArray[9], " \n";
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong? I've never done stuff with CSV files before so I'm not sure, only the names show up in the file but all of them are on the same line. Not sure why the age is not showing up either :/

Comment: `myfile << nameArray[1] << ',' << ageArray[1] << '\n';` Note also that an array declared as `std::string nameArray[9];` has nine elements, numbered 0 through 8. `nameArray[9]` exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an index out of bounds.

Comment: CSV is *not* a standard. So, pedantically speaking, there *is* no *correct* way.  There are various *defacto* standards though, but you need to know which one you are dealing with in order to produce something "correct".

Comment: do you have to use ' ' or can you use " "?

Answer (score 3):

Commas don't get output like that, you have to include the commas as chars to be output. Try this

```
myfile << nameArray[1] << ',' << ageArray[1] << ",\n";
```

instead of this

```
myfile << nameArray[1], ageArray[1], " \n";
```

As indicated in the comments there are various problems with CSV, like how to deal with spaces or other unusual characters embedded in text. The above code does not address those, but maybe it's enough for your purposes.

Also you have another error, you array indexes in the output statements go from 1 to 9, they should go from 0 to 8, since arrays in C++ start at zero.

Answer (score 1):

@john's answer is correct, in addition you have to start the index of `nameArray[]` and `ageArray[]` at `[0]`, not at `[1]` in C++ any array index starts at 0:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream myfile;

    const int numberOfInputs = 9;
    std::string nameArray[numberOfInputs] = {""};
    int ageArray[numberOfInputs] = {0};

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfInputs; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a name: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, nameArray[i]);
        std::cout << "Enter an age: ";
        std::cin >> ageArray[i];

        std::cin.get();
        myfile << nameArray[i], ageArray[i], " \n";
    }

    myfile.open("People.csv");
    myfile << "Name, Age, \n";
    myfile << nameArray[0] << ',' << ageArray[0] << '\n';
    myfile << nameArray[1] << ',' << ageArray[1] << '\n';
    myfile << nameArray[2] << ',' << ageArray[2] << '\n';
    myfile << nameArray[3] << ',' << ageArray[3] << '\n';
    myfile << nameArray[4] << ',' << ageArray[4] << '\n';
    myfile << nameArray[5] << ',' << ageArray[5] << '\n';
    myfile << nameArray[6] << ',' << ageArray[6] << '\n';
    myfile << nameArray[7] << ',' << ageArray[7] << '\n';
    myfile << nameArray[8] << ',' << ageArray[8] << '\n';
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```